# Attaching pdf to email does not send pdf from within iOS app

Tags: ios, email, pdf, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have an iOS app that should allow the user to select a pdf file and send it via there email account, I have the below code that presents the user with the email and shows the pdf attached, however with the email is send the pdf is not attached to the received email.

```
-(void)displayComposerSheet
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [picker setSubject:@"Public Holidays"];


    NSString *plistFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:currentCountry ofType:@"pdf"];

    NSData *myData = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistFilePath];
    [picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:currentCountry];

    // Fill out the email body text
    NSString *emailBody = @"Attached to this email is the PDF bought";
    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Is it a plist file or a PDF file? Is the file being found or is it nil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code is correct. You should check the filename. Is it a valid string(filename). Also presentModalViewController is deprecated. You should use presentViewController:animated:completion. Check this on device, not on simulator.

Comment: Yes it would see them filename is not valid for some reason, any ideas?

Comment: seems that the filename of the file was wrong, it was england_wales.pdf but the code should be "england wales.pdf" i renamed the file in xcode but it still shows wrong in the app

Comment: You should delete the app from device or simulator. Remove derived data. then run after Product->Clean